# Why REFL rule is primitive in HOL Light?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, proof-assistants, hol-light, hol

[HOL Light](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOL_Light#logical_foundations)
assumed `REFL` as a primitive.
Why does it need to do so?
Can't `REFL` rule be deduced in this way using `ASSUME` twice and `DEDUCT_ANTISYM_RULE` once?

$$\frac{\overline{\{p\}\vdash p} \quad \overline{\{p\}\vdash p}}{\vdash p = p}$$

Comment: I’m not sure, but it’s plausible this is just an optimization.  You’d have to apply the above derivation for each desired $p$ separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DEDUCT_ANTISYM_RULE` only applies to propositions, while `REFL` applies to all terms of all types. Your suggestion only shows that every propositions is equal (equivalent) to itself, but it could not be used to show that ever number equals itself.

Comment: Thank you Andrej